# Why close (and not delete) low quality question?

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

I just started reviewing low-quality posts. While for **answers** there's an option "Recommend Deletion", for **questions** there's only "Recommend Close".

So, if there's a question with very low quality (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154305/this-page-have-bug) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5474501)) why should I recommend closing it? Shouldn't I recommend deleting it (because if the question is just closed it's still findable through the search, right?)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are over [3.4 million registered users](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) on Stack Overflow. Not all of them will agree on what should be closed and deleted, and what shouldn't. Closing a low-quality question is an intermediary step that provides the original poster (or another altruist user) an opportunity to possibly improve the question and save it (or to just plain reopen it if it shouldn't have been closed in the first place).

This is why questions cannot normally be deleted right away even after they're closed. 10k+ users can only vote to delete a closed question after 2 days. For *extremely* bad content (with a score of -3 or less), 20k+ users can vote to delete a closed question right away.

Moderators, of course, can instantly delete any question, without having to close it first.